# T-SQL Stored Proc Update not Happening with trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm using an after update trigger on a table purely for testing purposes in order to force an error with an SSIS package. It's basically just a trigger that calls `RAISERROR()` with a static message after an update happens.

This works ok in most instances. However, when I call a specific stored procedure that contains a try/catch (no explicit transactions involved), and it updates the table, the update doesn't happen or is getting rolled back somehow. My understanding of Try/Catch was that it would not rollback unless you explicitly implemented `BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

I seem to be misunderstanding Try/Catch, or I'm misunderstanding how triggers function. I normally try not to use triggers, but for this use-case it made sense.

If I comment out the Try/Catch, everything functions as I'd expect.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MySproc
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        UPDATE dbo.MyTableToFireTrigger SET SomeColumn = 1 WHERE SomeColumn = 0

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --I'm able to log the after update trigger error message here, but it seems to be rolling back the update.
    END CATCH;
END
```

Trigger create:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTableToCauseTrigger
        AFTER UPDATE
        AS
        BEGIN
          RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);
        END;
```

Comment: Why use `RAISERROR()`, when `THROW` has been recommended (including on the documentation) since at least SQL Server 2012. As for why it isn't working, take the time to supply us with a [mre]. We don't have the trigger's or table's DDL here, for example.

Comment: It's just for testing purposes, and will probably never be used again. If there's a specific reason why RAISERROR() causes my issue and THROW won't, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This shouldn't require a minimal reproducable example. It's merely a question of functionality. The code isn't broken, it works on stored procs without the Try/Catch, and it works on this sproc if I remove the Try/Catch. I'm sure someone has knowledge of this behavior. I've tried googling but everything seems to reference explicit transactions.

Comment: Neither will change the behaviour. If you have a statement that fails in a batch, it's automatically rolled back. You have a state of 16 in `RAISERROR`, which means the transaction will not be commited. Then, in your `CATCH` you literally do nothing, and the error is (in effect) thrown away for no one to be aware of (and thus make it *appear* the `UPDATE` was successful even though though it was not).

Comment: So removing the Try/Catch makes it no longer a batch?

Comment: I do have logging in the catch block, but I removed it for simplicity as it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: They do have different behaviour `XACT_ABORT` is implicitly on in a trigger. `RAISERROR` is not honoured by `XACT_ABORT` but `THROW` is. Not sure why the `CATCH` block makes a difference

Comment: Personally, all these comments just cement more that `THROW` should be used, in my opinion @MartinSmith . Just like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) suggests: *"The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR."* That note is also ["new"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/4d365b6880e262204d03c6051545d12a41809f0f#diff-8491743fd98e4389da49308e80f769ef), as it wasn't there last time I visited that page.

Comment: The reason for the difference in behaviour is that the transaction is doomed when `XACT_ABORT` is `ON` and an error happens in a try block and can't be committed (`XACT_STATE` is `-1`). If you *really* need this odd behaviour you can `SET XACT_ABORT OFF;` in the trigger

Answer (score 0):

In a transaction if an error occurred that transaction will be rolled back. This refers to the  transaction concept. When you call your stored procedure a transaction is started. Then it causes your trigger to be fired and the error raised. Automatically the transaction will be rolled back.